# Selenium - Find element at other element level

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have following piece of code to read value from one field:

```
private final String dataRowXpath = "*//div[@ref='eCenterContainer']//div[@role='row']";
private final String nbrCellXpath = "//div[@col-id='tradeCount']//span"

List<WebElement> dataRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(dataRowXpath));

        WebElement row = dataRows
                .stream()
                .filter(row -> row.getAttribute("row-id").equals("USD"))
                .findFirst()
                .get();

String text = row.findElement(By.xpath(nbrCellXpath)).getText()
```

In this case I receive an empty string.

If I do it in this way with long xpath it reads correct value:

```
String xpath = "*//div[@ref='eCenterContainer']//div[@role='row' and @row-id='USD']" + nbrOfCellXpath;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
String text = element.getText();
```

So my question is why using findElement at WebElement *row* doesn't work.

I'd like to do it this way because I need to read more values from specific row elements so it would be better to have possibility to separate needed row first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find element inside element with XPath locator the XPath locator should start with a dot `.`.
So, in order to locate a cell inside a row with

```java
String text = row.findElement(By.xpath(nbrCellXpath)).getText()
```

please try defining the `nbrCellXpath` XPath expression as

```java
".//div[@col-id='tradeCount']//span"
```